# Convert from list of list to dictionary based on the first element of the list

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I was learning Python and came upon a problem: To convert a list of list to dictionary based on a certain key.

If the input is: `[['key1','h1'],['key2','h2'],['key3','h3'],['key1','h4'],['key1','h5'], ['key2','h6']]`

The output is: `{'key1':{'h1','h4','h5'}, 'key2':{'h2', 'h6'}, 'key3':{'h3'}}`

The logic being, the first element of the inner array is considered as the key for the new dictionary.
I am currently doing it the dirty way by iterating over the entire list. But, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to iterate over the list. One way is to use `dict.setdefault`:

```
out = {}
for k,v in lst:
    out.setdefault(k, set()).add(v)
```

This is the same as the following conditional loop:

```
out = {}
for k,v in lst:
    if k in out:
        out[k].add(v)
    else:
        out[k] = {v}
```

Output:

```
{'key1': {'h1', 'h4', 'h5'}, 'key2': {'h2', 'h6'}, 'key3': {'h3'}}
```